# I want to represent x1, x2, ..., xn (where their sum =1) by Dirichlet distribution. What alpha's should I select if x1, x2,... have the same pdf

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, dirichlet-distribution

I want to represent x1, x2, ..., xn (where their sum =1) by Dirichlet distribution. What alpha's should I select if x1, x2,...,xn have the same probability density function? all 0 < xi < 1. In that case, can I say that the dirichlet distribution is equivalent to a uniform closure? U(0,1)/sigma[U(0,1)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\sim\mathcal Dir(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$$then
$$X_i\sim\mathcal Be\left(\alpha_i,\sum_{j\ne i}\alpha_j\right)$$